# How can I create an HTA that enable close button after certain time period(15 sec)?

Tags: hta

How can I create an HTA that enable close button after certain time period(15 sec)?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Enable close button after 15 sec</title> 
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('close-button').style.display = 'inline';
    }, 15000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Close" name="close-button" id="close-button" style="display:none;" /> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: BTW, copy, paste and save file as xxx.hta, and then run it you will see.